# Rejection of app submission with Submission ID

Tags: swiftui

it's been twice since my app was being rejected from App Store Connect for the same reason. This is my first experience app submission, and I have no idea what is wrong with my app. I email them to provide the reason for rejection, but the replied answer has nothing to do with my app issue. Please let me know what is wrong with my submission. The two attachments below are all the information I received from them.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling? Ask to go up the chain seems weird

Comment: I asked them for a phone number to call them. But the service is pretty bad coz they keep sending emails instead. I just want to know what is wrong with my submission so that I can fix what is wrong. Based on their rejection, it looks like it has something to do with the version. What I can't understand is I don't even use TestFlight which has a complicated issue with the launch version. So, I start digging on the internet in order to find a similar issue with mine. Still there is no luck. So, posted here for helps. Thanks for your reply @loremipsum

Comment: There is no info to help. What do the other messages say? There is nobody from apple here that could tell you

Comment: This is what they keep sending me. "During our review, we noticed an issue with your submission.

Submission ID: 0828461f-24d3-49d6-ad2f-4a9dbda30d6e"

Comment: What do the other messages say? The one from 1 25. The ones that are not expanded in the screenshot